# Detect pdf landscpe with ssh pdfinfo

Tags: php, pdf

After researching to see how I can make PHP know the orientation of the pdf, and found a solution with pdfinfo, it works fine by bash. but I can't get that by PHP with executing exec command, I receive the response under the string to be able to create an if rule.
I do not understand why the if of the PHP does not work with the answer of the ssh.

```
    $test = shell_exec(' pdfinfo \
    -f 1 \
    -l 1 \
     sample.pdf \
| grep "Page.* size:" \
| \
 while read Page _pageno size _width x _height rest; do 
  [ "$(echo "${_width} / 1"|bc)" -gt "$(echo "${_height} / 1"|bc)" ] \
     && echo "landscape" \
    || echo "portrait"  ; \
 done');

if($test=="portrait"){
    echo "run script from portrait";
}else{
    echo"run script from landscape";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be white space in the returned value. Use `trim($test)` before the `if` condition to trim the white space.

Comment: It seems that at the end of the answer in $ test it is a pause that I don't know where it comes from. now if it works for me. Thank you, I was not thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just var_dump($test) and see what's returned?

Comment: portrait is the answare